# Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Cannot deploy function with runtime node16

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Why do I get the error, when watching a directory for Cloud Functions, and how can I resolve this error?

> Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Cannot deploy function with runtime node16

My curent node version that I am using is `v16.16.0`

firebase.json

```json
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "dist/apps/andika-backend",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "node tools/scripts/build-gc-functions-package.js"
      ],
      "runtime": "node16"
    }
  ],
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 4402
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 6211
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9301
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "singleProjectMode": true
  },
  "hosting": {
    "target": "andika",
    "public": "dist/andika",
    "ignore": [
      "**/.*"
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "*.[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f].+(css|js)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "public,max-age=31536000,immutable"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "/@(ngsw-worker.js|ngsw.json)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Comment: Have you tried  downgrading the runtime node version?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at [Set up Node.js and the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#set-up-node.js-and-the-firebase-cli) says:

> In many cases, new features and bug fixes are available only with the
> latest version of the Firebase CLI and the firebase-functions SDK.
> It's a good practice to frequently update both the Firebase CLI and
> the SDK with these commands inside the functions folder of your
> Firebase project:
>
> ```
> npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
> npm install -g firebase-tools
> ```

Comment: I have the latest version installed but the error output is the same

Comment: can you try downgarding the runtime node version to node14 and check

Answer (score 0):

Change `"runtime": "node16"` to `"runtime": "nodejs16"`.